# Any other alternative for require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In the process of modularising my java script code base, I had to break my single java script file to a couple of java script files. To resolve dependencies, we used require.js. But as per some restriction I cannot use require.js. Is there any other alternative or any piece of code that can do resolve the dependency issue?

Comment: There's some other require-like libraries, have a look around on google. Depending on how your modules are written, you might even be able to write it yourself in a couple of lines, since you basically just create/insert new script tags until all modules have been loaded in order.

Comment: you should visit this,check the documentation,it may help you....http://www.slant.co/topics/3645/versus/~webpack_vs_browserify_vs_qoopido-demand

Answer (score 0):

There's a great video you should watch to come up to speed with the latest in module bundlers. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-NmkKVEhoI

But overall, there are 3 module standards you can use: Commonjs, AMD, ES6 modules. (RequireJS is built off of commonjs)

ES6 is the way to go to future-proof your code. Webpack handles only Commonjs and AMD(Es6 can be added-on using babel-loader or such), but JSPM can handle all 3 standards in parallel. If you use only ES6 modules, you can use Rollup.

Comment: Thanks, however the above youtube link does not exists, please share the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try ZeroDep

https://github.com/SimonChong/ZeroDep

Its very different from the standard module definitions but it works well, is lightweight and is simple.